How do i modify image in python to fit face_recognition parameters (8bit gray or RGB image)
I'm trying to modify my image so that it fits the supported image type.
I've tried using cv2 and Pillow to modify the dtype however it returns the error "RuntimeError: Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image.".
Here is the code:
image = cv2.imread("myimage.jpeg")
print(f"Original dtype : {image.dtype}, shape: {image.shape}")
'''Output: Original dtype : uint8, shape: (720, 1080, 3)'''

image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(f"Converted dtype: {image_rgb.dtype}, shape: {image_rgb.shape}")
'''Output: Converted dtype: uint8, shape: (720, 1080, 3)'''

pil_image = Image.fromarray(image_rgb)
image_rgb = np.array(pil_image)

image_rgb = image_rgb.astype(np.uint8)
print(f'Final dtype: {image_rgb.dtype}, shape: {image_rgb.shape}')
'''Output: Final dtype: uint8, shape: (720, 1080, 3)'''



face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image_rgb)
print(face_locations)
'''Output: RuntimeError: Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image.'''


Why are you mixing OpenCV and PIL? What happens if you pass the image converted by OpenCV directly (image_rgb)? OpenCV reads images as numpy arrays, I don't understand why you need PIL here if you end up casting the image to a numpy array anyway. You don't even have a PIL object in the first place...

Use cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

@stateMachine I tried both of them individually and neither gave me the desired result and after looking for solutions on here I couldn’t find anything so I just tried this out of desperation

@fmw42 tired that’s, unfortunately I still get the same error

Probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/78638053/3962537 This needs details about the versions of the libraries installed.

submit an issue to the "face-recognition" library.

@DanMašek Thank you this solved my issue!

You have absolutely nothing to do, you can use a normal image!
import face_recognition as fr
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

face_locations = fr.face_locations(img)

print(face_locations)

for (top, right, bottom, left) in face_locations:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)



